# ion-virtual-scroll flickers when content gets updated

Tags: typescript, angular9, ionic5

I am facing an issue with `ion-virtual-scroll`. When the content updated the list gets flickered.

### Html

```
<ion-virtual-scroll [items]="dataList" [trackBy]="trackByFn" approxItemHeight="1020px">
      <div *virtualItem="let item;let id=index">
          <div *ngFor="let data of item.list">
           .......
          </div>
      <div>
<ion-virtual-scroll>
```

### ts file

```
public  trackByFn(index, item) {
  return item? item.id:index;
}
```

this is the service call from which i am getting data

```
    this.dataService.getData()
          .pipe(distinctUntilChanged((prev, curr) => JSON.stringify(prev) === JSON.stringify(curr)))
          .subscribe(resp=>{
               ----
               ----
}
```

Any suggestion how to avoid this?